# Possible to shift rows in for loops? (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

i'm trying to make a for loop that calculates returns over a six month period based on what category the stock is. I thus have 3 DataFrames i use to do this, which are the following:

df = stock prices for a given month

WinnerLoser_df = Indicates whether a stock is shorted (-1) or longed (1)

portf_df = empty DataFrame where the returns should be stored.

I'm trying for each stock (column) to calculate the return over a 6 month period based on the signal (-1 or 1). So the return for stock x will be based on the signal 6 months prior, which i why i subtract 6 in the code.

```
portf_df = pd.DataFrame(index = WinnerLoser_df.index , columns = WinnerLoser_df.columns)


for i in WinnerLoser_df.columns:
    for j in range(230, len(WinnerLoser_df)):
        portf_df[i][j] = WinnerLoser_df[i - 6][j] * (df[i][j] / df[i - 6][j])

print(portf_df.tail(10))
```

This does however yield an error, because i subtract 6, i've tried to use .shift(), but that doesn't work.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
      5 for i in WinnerLoser_df.columns:
      6     for j in range(230, len(WinnerLoser_df)):
----> 7         portf_df[i][j] = WinnerLoser_df[i - 6][j] * (df[i][j] / df[i - 6][j])
      8 
      9 print(portf_df.tail(10))

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
```

Is there any alternative way to shift the rows in the for loop?

Comment: I would propose to compute six months returns via df.pct_change(6*20) and multiply this directly with your WinnerLoser_df dataframe to get the strategy return. No need for using for loops outside of pandas if I understand your question right.

Comment: I haven't thought of that! It's not the fancy looping solution, but it works, thanks a lot!